# Laravel query builder returns empty result set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying so hard to understand the reason why my code in `Laravel` Controller and the `SQL` statement I have used return empty result set, while as you will view a screenshot of my `PhpMyAdmin` page, there is a table created and it contains the data just as I have requested the codes in the `HomeController.php`. Here are the codes and pictures of `SQL` and `PhpMyAdmin` page:
`HomeController.php :`

```
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $table_name = $user_name . '_' . $user_id;
        $return_value = 'The user\'s Table is now present : ' . $table_name;

        if (Schema::hasTable($table_name))
        {   
            $langs = DB::table($table_name)->get();
            return view('home', ['rvalue' => $langs]);
        }else{
            Schema::connection('mysql')->create($table_name, function ($table){
                $value = 'necro';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('en')->default($value);
                $table->string('fr')->default($value);
                $table->string('sp')->default($value);
            });

            $langs = DB::table($table_name)->get();
            return view('home', ['rvalue' => $langs]);

        }
```

`MySQL commanding to check the database :`
[image]

`PhpMyAdmin :`
[image]

Would you please help me understand what is wrong in my codes that are placed in `HomeController.php`? I have created the database using phpmyadmin with Utf8_General_ci coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's returning an empty set because the table actually is empty. The phpadmin screenshot shows the structure for the table, but not it's content.

```
 Schema::connection('mysql')->create($table_name, function ($table){
            $value = 'necro';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('en')->default($value);
            $table->string('fr')->default($value);
            $table->string('sp')->default($value);
        });

        $langs = DB::table($table_name)->get();
        return view('home', ['rvalue' => $langs]);
```

In this piece of code, you only create a table, but never add any data to it.

Comment: Dear friend, Thank you very much to ease my pain which was caused by my lack of knowledge. I used to think that using the `->default($value)` would enter the value into the database by itself. I Wish you the best of luck.